# Webpack doesn't show new build errors after a failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Webpack stops and shows an error in the bundle. If I fix that error it will happily rebundle. If I fix an error and it finds another error it will not show the new error. It shows the first error. I have to kill webpack and re-run it to show the new error.

Any ideas how to always show the most recent error?

package.json webpack scripts command:

```
"dev": "webpack -d --watch --progress",
```

I'm running webpack run dev, and above is the dev command config

Comment: How are you running webpack? Show us your script or command.

Comment: I have updated the OP

Comment: Does running the command directly (i.e. `webpack -d -w`) show the same problem?

Comment: yes it's the same. if I fix the displayed error, it will now show the new error. I have to stop and restart webpack.

Comment: Obvious question, but do you see the terminal scroll down when your file changes? Meaning, you're not simply seeing the old output? If that's the case, then what editor are you using to save your files? It's possible that it does a swap-and-replace save, which could confuse webpack and cause it to parse the old version of the file, resulting in the same error. Look for "atomic save" option (to overwrite the file directly when saving), and see if that changes webpack's behavior.

Comment: Yes it appears to be the way that atom editor saves file. I'll have to investigate further how I can resolve it, but it looks to be related to this. If you can move your comment to an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that webpack is actually watching and reloading the files (check if the terminal scrolls down when you change one of your files), then it's probably something unusual going on with the way that your editor is saving your files.

For example, if your editor uses a "save and swap" technique, it's possible that webpack sees the old version of the file and loads that instead of the new version, thus showing you the original error. Check for editor settings related to "atomic saves" and such. The same situation can also be caused by temporary or backup files that your webpack configuration picks up as proper source files.